# Parameter selection values from database

Tags: teamcity, parameter-passing

In TC it is possible to create parameterized builds and these build parameters can use a selection box.

I am looking for a way to dynamically fill the values which can be selected. The best case would be that I could define a query (same database as the TC server) and get the values, but I would be also happy to see some kind of workaround by using environment variables or a file that contains the values.

Answer (score 0):

As of TeamCity 7.1 this is not possible. You can define parameters and use have them in a select (or multi-select) list but the values must be defined in advance at configuration time not at build time.

You can access and change build parameters from the [TeamCity REST API](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin#RESTAPIPlugin-BuildConfigurationAndTemplateSettings) but it only allows you to change the default value, not the available options in the select list. Maybe a future version of the REST API will enable this.